# Field injection of a service in AuthenticationSuccessHandler in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot

in my app I have an `Account` class which also implements `UserDetails`. I also created class `MyAuthenticaionSuccessHandler` which extends `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler`. What I want is to change a field `dateLastLogin` on `Account` after user logs in. In method `onAuthenticationSuccess` I want instance of `AccountService` in which method `save(Account account)` exist, to save updated `Account` to db. The problem begins here. I can't do field injection, because I have to initialize an instance of `AccountService` in constructor. I can't do that, because then I won't be able to create an instance of `MyAuthenticaionSuccessHandler`. I also can't create it manually. Instances of other classes like services or controllers in which instances of other service/repository classes are created automatically, so there it works. But how to make it work for custom authentication success handler?
Here are pieces of my code:

Piece of class that extends WebSecurityConfigureAdapter

```
// ...
   .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/guest/login")
        .permitAll()
        .failureHandler(new MyAuthenticationFailureHandler("/guest/login"))
        .successHandler(new MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler("/user/overview"))
        .and()
    .logout()
//  ...
```

Piece of AccountService

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class AccountService implements UserDetailsService {
    private final AccountRepository accountRepository;
    private final ActivationCodeService activationCodeService;
    public AccountService(AccountRepository accountRepository, ActivationCodeService activationCodeService) {
        this.accountRepository = accountRepository;
        this.activationCodeService = activationCodeService;
    }

    public void saveAccount(Account account){
        accountRepository.save(account);
    }
// ...
```

And my own authentication success handler

```
public class MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    private final AccountService accountService; // <-- here it doesn't work

    public MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
    }

    public MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler(String defaultTargetUrl) {
        super(defaultTargetUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
        Account account = (Account)authentication.getPrincipal();
        account.setDateLastLogin(new Date());
        accountService.saveAccount(account);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are createing an instance outside the scope of Spring. It isn't a bean and as such isn't available for all the Spring goodness. Write an `@Bean` method for those handlers and refer to them, that will make them beans and get injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `new` to create an object directly in a spring application. What you can do is create a bean using `@Bean` annotation and autowire it using `@Autowired` annotation.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration() {

  @Bean
  public MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler myAuthenticationSuccessHandler (){
  return new MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler("/user/overview");
  }
}

---

@Autowired
private MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler myAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
```

Comment: You can just define it in the same class as an `@Bean` method and then reference that method. No need to autowire it.

Answer (score 0):

In looking at your code I don't see any reason why you cannot inject `AccountService` into `MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler`.  If the code you've posted is your exact code, then the problems lies in

`.successHandler(new MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler("/user/overview"))`

because by using `new` here, you've taken Spring completely out of the equation and aren't getting any injections into `MyAuthenticationFailureHandler`.

In your `WebSecurityConfigureAdapter` try adding a member variable

```
@Autowired
private MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler myAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
```

then, in your chain, add it like so

```
.successHandler(myAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
```

If you absolutely must have parameters in this bean constructor (the url), then you'll need to create a BeanFactory that produces a Spring bean of type `MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler` that contains your url.